# Python subprocess.check_output

Tags: python

I am trying to use a couple shell level commands from Python to get and set variables for later use in my program but it does not appear to be calling the commands properly as the outputs should be simple 1-liners. Not quite sure if it's due to the % or ; signs.

```
current_vcodec = subprocess.check_output(["mediainfo", "--Inform='Video;%CodecID%'", "%s" % source])
current_acodec = subprocess.check_output(["mediainfo", "--Inform='Audio;%CodecID%'", "%s" % source])
duration = subprocess.check_output(["mediainfo", "--Inform='Video;%Duration%'", "%s" % source])
```

Comment: Check into `subprocess.Popen()`.https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen  I've had far more luck with this with it's `communicate()` method than anything else.

Comment: @Will, yeah but `subprocess.check_output()` is a wrapper around `communicate()` under the hood...

Comment: @Eroji, can you describe what output you are currently getting? Or post it? Or is there a relevant traceback we could take a look at? It might also be helpful to post what the expected output looks like, e.g. if you just run the command in a shell

Comment: Instead of giving a single line of the codec used, it's giving the full mediainfo output of the file.

Comment: Perhaps you should remove the `'` characters. A shell would remove them, but `check_output` doesn't open a shell - it passes the string as-is.

Comment: I just did a test using same format but calling echo instead to output what it's formulating as the command for mediainfo. Everything looks right and pasting that into shell also gives the expected output. Must admit I'm at a loss now...

Comment: I thought about that too, but the problem is, it needs the quote there to tell mediainfo I only want a specific value. Without them, the command does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it working. This is the syntax that gave the correct output.

```
current_vcodec = subprocess.check_output("mediainfo --Inform='Video;%%CodecID%%' %s" % source, shell=True)
current_acodec = subprocess.check_output("mediainfo --Inform='Audio;%%CodecID%%' %s" % source, shell=True)
duration = subprocess.check_output("mediainfo --Inform='Video;%%Duration%%' %s" % source, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you use Kenneth Reitz's [envoy](https://github.com/kennethreitz/envoy) python wrapper for subprocess.  It makes calls to command line far easier to use.

```
import envoy
res = envoy.run("mediainfo --Inform='Video;%CodecID%' {0}".format(source))
if res.status_code != 0:
   print("media info failure: {0}".format(res.std_out + " " + res.std_err))
 else:
   print(res.std_out)
   current_vcodec = res.std_out
```

If you needed, you can "escape" the % with a backslash, but I'm not sure that's the problem. The ; shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It does not appear to be the % sign after some testing, but still not working... If possibly I want to stick with subprocess (it sucks :/) just for the sake of portability.

Comment: I understand.  But having worked with subprocesses warts for so long, I've found envoy worth the effort :)

Comment: I'll definitely try it out. I personally would not have any problems using it. Thanks!